# SAP ASE Extension Python Module: @stmt_query_timeout?

Tags: python-3.x, sybase, pyodbc, sap-ase

I am trying to move from a Windows-based pyodbc (Using the SAP Adaptive Server Enterprise 16.0 driver) to Red Hat Linux 7.9-based sybpydb solution.

Current pyodbc solution:

```
connection = pyodbc.connect(
   "Driver={Adaptive Server Enterprise};NetworkAddress=<servername,serverport>;
    Database=<database>;UID={<username>};PWD={<password>};@pool_size=10;
    stmtquery_timeout=1200;@login_timeout=30;@connection_timeout=30")
df = pandas.read_sql_query("exec <storedproc_name>")
connection.close()
```

I am trying to replicate this under linux using the sybclient-16.0.3-2 package.

```
import sybpydb

connection = sybpydb.connect(user=username, password=password, servername=servername,
                             dsn="HostName=<hostname>;Database=<database>;LoginTimeout=30;Timeout=30")

curr = connection.cursor()
result = cursor.execute("exec <storedproc_name>")
```

Passing `@smtmquery_timeout=1200` causes the connection to fail. But without this, the call to the stored proc will timeout. I can't see anything in the documentation about this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the document:
https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_ASE_SDK/a1576559612d4e39886fc0ad4e093074/b0fd2586bbf910148c6ac638f6594153.html

There is no attribute: smtmquery_timeout

If you are using "sybpydb", you can use the openclient sdk directly instead of the ODBC style configuration for the connection.